# Explicit specialization of member function template in source file

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-specialization

I have a class with a member template function:

```
// writer.h
class Writer {
public:
    ...
    template <typename T, typename V>
    void addField(const std::string& name, V v) 
    {
        // write something
    }
};
```

And in Writer's source file, I added explicit specializations for `some_type`:

```
// writer.cpp
template <>
void Writer::addField<some_type, int>(const std::string& name, int v)
{
    // specific some_type writing logic
}
```

This works... sometimes. Even if I definitely make sure that I have the right types:

```
writer.addField<some_type>("name", static_cast<int>(some_value));
```

Sometimes the explicit specialization gets called, and sometimes the primary gets called. What gives?

Comment: Under Visual Studio its a compiler bug: [Explicit specialization of C++ struct member template functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6083948/608639).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Declaring specializations in a source file and can cause all sorts of subtle issues that are very difficult to diagnose. The compiler isn't obligated to help you in any regard here either. The standard **strongly encourages you not to do this**, with the help of a limerick, in [temp.expl.spec]/6-7:

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that specialization
>   shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation
>   to take place, **in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required**. If the program
>   does not provide a definition for an explicit specialization and either the specialization is used in a way
>   that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place or the member is a virtual member function, the
>   program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. An implicit instantiation is never generated for an explicit
>   specialization that is declared but not defined.
>
> The placement of explicit specialization declarations for function templates, class templates, variable templates,
>   member functions of class templates, [...], etc., can affect whether a program is well-formed according
>   to the relative positioning of the explicit specialization declarations and their points of instantiation
>   in the translation unit as specified above and below. **When writing a specialization, be careful about its
>   location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation**.

It's likely that in some translation units, the specialization happened to be declared before the first use - and in some translation units it hasn't been. It's better to avoid all such issues entirely by simply declaring your specialization in your header:

```
// writer.h
class Writer {
public:
    ...
    template <typename T, typename V>
    void addField(const std::string& name, V v) 
    { /* ... */ }
};

// still writer.h
template <>
inline void Writer::addField<some_type, int>(const std::string& name, int v)
{ /* ... */ }
```

You can also just *declare* it in the header (no longer needs to be inline), and still define it in the source.

Comment: If it's in the header, you need to make it `inline`; alternatively, you can *declare* the specialization in the header, and *define* it elsewhere.

Comment: @T.C. Ah, oops. Total omission on my part.