# Template specialization with enable_if

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, enable-if

I'm trying to create a template function taking a typename. I want to specialize this templates for some basic types like `int`, `long`, `string` and `double`. For all others types, i need to have a specialized code for class/struct, and a default code for others types.

My current code is this one :

```
// Declaration
template <typename T, typename enable_if<is_class<T>::value>::type = 0>
void test(T& value);

template <typename T, typename enable_if<!is_class<T>::value>::type = 0>
void test(T& value);

template <> // What am i supposed to write here ?
void test<int>(int& value);

// Definition
template <typename T, typename enable_if<is_class<T>::value>::type = 0>
void test(T& value) {
    cout << "Class/struct test" << endl;
}

template <typename T, typename enable_if<!is_class<T>::value>::type = 0>
void test(T& value) {
    cout << "Other types test" << endl;
}

template <>
void test<int>(int& value) {
    cout << "int test" << endl;
}
```

This code won't compile. I can't figure what am i suppoed to write in the `int` specialized template.

I'm trying to use [the examples from this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), but i'm unable to make it work.

Comment: when `is_class<T>::value` is true, `enable_if<is_class<T>::value>::type` is `void`. You try to assign `0` to `void`.

Comment: Did you read the notes in the link you posted? It almost literally describes your mistake.

Comment: It's better to use an overloaded function for this purpose, because you cannot partially specialize a function template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typename enable_if<is_class<T>::value>::type = 0` doesn't make sense, because `typename enable_if<is_class<T>::value>::type` would refer to `void`; you can change it to `typename enable_if<is_class<T>::value>::type* = nullptr`. Then for the full specialization for `int`, note that `test` has two template parameters, then

```
// Declaration
template <typename T, typename enable_if<is_class<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void test(T& value);

template <typename T, typename enable_if<!is_class<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void test(T& value);

template <>
void test<int, nullptr>(int& value);

// Definition
template <typename T, typename enable_if<is_class<T>::value>::type*>
void test(T& value) {
    cout << "Class/struct test" << endl;
}

template <typename T, typename enable_if<!is_class<T>::value>::type*>
void test(T& value) {
    cout << "Other types test" << endl;
}

template <>
void test<int, nullptr>(int& value) {
    cout << "int test" << endl;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lu8y5KgWHgtdLsir)

Or simply put `typename enable_if<is_class<T>::value>::type` as the return type. e.g.

```
// Declaration
template <typename T>
typename enable_if<is_class<T>::value>::type test(T& value);

template <typename T>
typename enable_if<!is_class<T>::value>::type test(T& value);

template <>
void test<int>(int& value);

// Definition
template <typename T>
typename enable_if<is_class<T>::value>::type test(T& value) {
    cout << "Class/struct test" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
typename enable_if<!is_class<T>::value>::type test(T& value) {
    cout << "Other types test" << endl;
}

template <>
void test<int>(int& value) {
    cout << "int test" << endl;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3esikOMncZ9VYhqX)

Comment: interestingly it doesn't compile for Visual Studio `Error C2912 explicit specialization 'void test<int,nullptr>(int &)' is not a specialization of a function template`

Comment: @StackDanny Emm... It seems the 2nd version works for MSVS. https://rextester.com/QTLR35350

Comment: @songyuanyao yes, I just tried it when you edited. works fine. But it's still weird, also has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083948/explicit-specialization-of-c-struct-member-template-functions-is-this-a-visu)

Comment: `void test<int>(int &)` version also compiles with MSVS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use std::enable_if in function argument instead of a template parameter:

```
// Declaration
template <typename T>
void test(T& value, enable_if_t<is_class<T>::value>* = nullptr);

template <typename T>
void test(T& value, enable_if_t<!is_class<T>::value>* = nullptr);

template <>
void test<int>(int& value, enable_if_t<!is_class<int>::value>*);

// Definition
template <typename T>
void test(T& value, enable_if_t<is_class<T>::value>*){
    cout << "Class/struct test" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void test(T& value, enable_if_t<!is_class<T>::value>*) {
    cout << "Other types test" << endl;
}

template <>
void test<int>(int& value, enable_if_t<!is_class<int>::value>*) {
    cout << "int test" << endl;
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to put it as a template parameter if done properly. This pollutes the function signature, and IMO is harder to read as well.

Comment: Yeah, agree. The template parameter is better